# How get URL Parameters in HTACCESS

Tags: php, .htaccess

here is my code

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/search/$ products.php?catName=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ products.php?catName=$1 [L]
```

if i open the URL `http://my-site.com/men/`
in products.php if i use `print_r($_REQUEST);` its show following output

```
[catName] => men
[_fjtads1] => 336
```

if i open the URL `http://my-site.com/men/search/?pricemin=1000&pricemax=4000`
i am getting same in products.php

```
[catName] => men
[_fjtads1] => 336
```

How can i get `pricemin` and `pricemax` parameters? please help me.

**SOLVED**

If i used `[QSA]` instead `[L]` its workinginf for me

Comment: `$_GET['pricemin']` and `$_GET['pricemax']`

Comment: @KheshavSewnundun hi bro thanks for your reply but its not working.

Answer (score 0):

You can access them via get Parameters:

```
<?php
echo $_GET['pricemin'];
echo $_GET['pricemax'];
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If i used `[QSA]` instead `[L]` its workinginf for me